# циклический сдвиг элементов массива вправо

Tags: php

осуществляю циклический сдвиг элементов массива вправо,получаю Notice: Undefined offset: 10 т.е я неверно сместил массив,как исправить мой код

```
$arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$temp = $arr[count($arr)-1];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{    
  echo $arr[$i]." ";
}

 for($i = count($arr); $i >=1; $i--){
     $arr[$i+1] = $arr[$i] ;
 }
 $arr[0] = $temp;
 print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Какой результат вы ожидаете - 10 элементов  (1,1,....,9) или  11 элементов (1, 1,... 9,10) ?

Comment: @splash58 вот такой ответ 10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = count($arr)-2; $i>=0; $i--){
    $arr[$i+1] = $arr[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем последний и переставляем на первое место

```
array_unshift($arr, array_pop ($arr));
```

Comment: гуглить и я умею,мне нужно поправить то что я написал

Comment: Ну что, специалист по гуглу, разобрался?

Comment: я использовал ответ  Archie O'Hare,но все равно немного нето, жду еще ответы

Comment: а гуглить не помогает ? :)

Comment: родной угомонись,а?

Comment: где ж тебя вежливости-то учили.  вот тут поправленный твой код https://eval.in/377393 глядишь, разберешься

Comment: а вот теперь спасибо ;)

Comment: Вообще-то на этом сайте принято отмечать правильные ответыю Ты этого, я смотрю, не делаешь, судя по статистике,  а зря.